# What is the third airport near Dubai visible on Google Maps?

Tags: airport-identification

I know Dubai International (DXB) and Dubai World Central (DWC). What is [the third Dubai Airport](https://goo.gl/maps/Eag38sGjUwS2), not named on Google Maps?

Is it military, GA or commercial. Why there is no clear access road to it?

Comment: Zooming in a little more, it identifies the airport as [Al Minhad Air Base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al_Minhad_Air_Base). Turning on Google Earth view, you can see a single road leading to the airbase from the east.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The airport is [Al Minhad Air Base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al_Minhad_Air_Base):

> Al Minhad Air Base is a military installation in the United Arab Emirates. The base is located approximately 15 miles (24 km) south of Dubai and is operated by the United Arab Emirates Air Force. It is currently the headquarters of Joint Task Force 633 and supports Australian operations in the Middle East.

[image]

If you turn on Google Earth view, you can see the single road leading into the airbase from the east:

[image]

Comment: [Camelicious](http://www.camelicious.ae/home.php) :)

Comment: I was curious as to what it was but was afraid to look it up.

Comment: Thank you @Steve for adding the link and making the day just a bit brighter!

Comment: @Steve Ooops, I am too late! :( "PAGE NOT FOUND" (http://camelicious.ae/home.php).

Comment: @trejder The 404 page still includes the text "Over 35 years ago, the idea of a camel-milking facility was born at the Central Veterinary Research Laboratory (CVRL) in Dubai", "Emirates Industry for Camel Milk & Products" and the "Emirates Camel Goodness" logo. So it appears to be a camel dairy, for want of a better phrase.